# Send Hangouts chat message(Not SMS message) to specific number through code

Tags: android, google-hangouts

I have googled this but cannot find an answer, do someone know how to send android Hangouts chat message to specific number through code?

Answer (score 1):

Using this you can open both hangout and messenger app.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("smsto:"));

//Adding message which is to be sent (both are compulsory to compensate for all android versions)
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "shareMessage");
intent.putExtra("sms_body", "shareMessage");

//Addres which is to be sent to (Optional)
intent.putExtra("address", "12125551212"); //Optional
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, are you saying using Hangout App? which is built in as SMS app?

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
smsIntent.putExtra("address", "12125551212");
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body","Body of Message");
startActivity(smsIntent);
```

Comment: No, not SMS message but chat message.